# How to access route params: through a fully nuxt-i18n localized route? (localeLocation vs localePath)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt-i18n

Does nuxt/VueRouter always need to have a `_some.vue` file name to pick up route params?

I wanted to have a button like so:

```html
<NuxtLink :to="localePath({ name: 'musicdb', params: { search: page.shortTitle }})">
  Search Title
</NuxtLink>
```

and send params to my route `/musicdb/index.vue` but this apparently does not work ...

however it works fine with a query string ...

```html
<NuxtLink :to="localePath({ name: 'musicdb', query: { search: page.shortTitle }})">
  Search Title
</NuxtLink>
```

Why does `params:` not work with an index.vue file? I am assuming it is a (base) routing issue?

`params:` called within `index.vue` are `undefined` and do not work!

```js
<script> 
// /musicdb/index.vue page
export default {
created() {
    console.log(this.$route.params.search); // undefined
    this.query = this.$route.params.search;
}
...
```

query string works fine:

```js
<script> 
// /musicdb/index.vue page
export default {
created() {
    console.log(this.$route.query.search); // "hello search string"
    this.query = this.$route.query.search;
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, you'll need

```html
<nuxt-link :to="localeLocation({ name: 'test', params: { userId: '123' } })">
  Go to the test page with some fancy params
</nuxt-link>
```

Then, `this.$route.params` will properly show `{ userId: "123" }`.

This one got released not so long ago in `v6.24.0`: https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module/releases/tag/v6.24.0

An upgrade may be needed. Further explanation can be found at the bottom of this page: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/basic-usage/#nuxt-link

---

PS: `localePath` alone will not work because it
will return a full path but you cannot use params with a path as explained [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort), rather we need a `name`. Hence `localeLocation` is the solution here, because it will provide us the full Vue-router object.

Comment: Warning: at this time, the `.params` property only works when `localeLocation()` is pushed with `.name'. It does not work with a `.path`

Eg: `localeLocation({ name: 'index', params: { userId: 1 })` works, but `localeLocation({ path: '/', params: { userId: 1 })` does not.

Comment: @AdonisGaitatzis yeah, this is how the vue router actually works: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort